# What does the は in this sentence do?

Tags: grammar, particle-は

> 力任せに壁面に罅{ひび}を**刻んでは一つ**、また一つと体のパーツを外気に晒{さら}していく。

What does は do here? Is it contrasting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[V1] + ては + [V2]` or `[V1] + では + [V2]` is a fixed expression that describes two actions (V1, V2) are repeatedly happening in rapid succession.

See [ては](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/152199/m0u/) definition 3:

> ３ 二つの動作・作用などが対になって繰り返される意を表す。「幼い頃は電車を見**ては**喜んでいた」「姉はいつも洋服を脱い**では**着て楽しんでいる」

So this sentence means that someone is repeating the two actions (壁面に罅【ひび】を刻む and パーツを外気に晒【さら】す) again and again.