# The meaning of 来なんだ (a seemingly archaic form)

Tags: grammar, verbs, kansai-ben, archaic-language

Situation from a story: 侍A is pursuing 侍B. 侍A meets 町人C and interrogates him:

> 侍B (some description)、逃げては来なんだかな。

I guess it must mean something like "didn't he come here while running away?"

I cannot quite understand the form 来なんだかな here. The answer to [this question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1287751347) suggests 来なん is a phrase expressing a desire. It does not seem to be the case, where 侍A seemingly is wondering.

Comment: In my original question I also asked about 〜ては form here. This has already been answered [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27636/11104)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

来なんだ = 来なかった. The negative past. You often hear this form in 時代劇 and from old people in fiction (think [波平]{なみへい} in Sazaesan, Dumbledore in Harry Potter...)

> **デジタル大辞泉**の解説
>   **なんだ［助動］**
>
> ［助動］［なんだら｜なんで（なんだり）｜なんだ｜なんだ（なんだる）｜なんだれ｜○］動詞型活用語の未然形に付く。過去の打消しの意を表す。なかった。
>   [補説]語源は未詳。打消しの助動詞「ぬ」に「あった」の付いた「ぬあった」の音変化とみる説や、打消しの「なん」に過去の「た」が付いた助動詞からとする説など、諸説がある。室町時代から江戸後期まで用いられたが、江戸末期からは「なかった」がそれに代わった。現在では、主に関西方言に行われる。
>   「売薬の外は誰にも逢わ**なんだ**ことは」〈鏡花・高野聖〉
>   「実否ヲ未ダ決シサセラレ**ナンダレ**バ」〈天草本伊曽保・イソポが生涯〉
>   「物しったり物しら**なんだ**り、物しり物しらずさ」〈滑・浮世床・初〉

[Digital Daijisen](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0-590581) gives a couple of theories about the development of this form and tells us it was used from the Muromachi era to the late Edo era, after which ～なかった took over. It goes on to say that in the modern era the form remains mainly in Kansai dialects.

Regarding its modern usage in Kansai Japanese, [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%B0%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80#.E5.85.B1.E9.80.9A.E8.AA.9E.E3.82.84.E4.BB.96.E6.96.B9.E8.A8.80.E3.81.A8.E3.81.AE.E6.8E.A5.E8.A7.A6.E3.81.AB.E3.82.88.E3.82.8B.E5.A4.89.E5.8C.96.E3.81.AE.E4.BE.8B) says that ～んかった is becoming more popular than ～なんだ which fits with my impression:

> 西日本に多い否定の助動詞「ん」の過去表現は本来「…なんだ」であるが「ん」と共通語「…なかった」が交じり合って「…んかった」という形が生まれ、「…なんだ」に取って代わりつつある。
>   （例）知らなんだ→知らんかった