# Questions about 「とは」and 「思わなんだ」

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, particle-は, particle-と, negation

Here is the sentence relating to the questions.

> こんなうすぎたねえ車の中で　また　おあいできる**とは思わなんだ**ぜ。

1) Why is the 「は」included with the particle 「と」? I think only 「と」would be enough to be used with the verb 「思う」. Or the 「は」used for emphasizing?

2) I think 「い」is missing to make the verb 「思う」 negative, becoming 「思わな**い**んだ」. Or is this an exceptional case or something of the verb conjugation?

Comment: I answered a similar question about this kind of conjugation recently if you wanna have a look btw: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28964/the-meaning-of-%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0-a-seemingly-archaic-form/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/why-is-the-topic-marker-often-used-in-negative-statements-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e6%80%9d%e3%82%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

Comment: It is duplicate for the question 1) but it did not answer question 2).

Comment: @George You asked two questions in one, and each is a duplicate but of a different question.  2) is answered by Ash's link.  It means 思わなかった, not 思わないんだ.